# Yii2: Удалить несколько записей из базы, одним обращением. (удаление согласно параметрам из массива)

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Есть ли какая нибудь фукнциональность, противоположная `batchInsert()`?

Где бы параметрами передавались.

`('table_name', [ column_name1 , ... , column_name3], [params1[], ..., params3[]])`

И работа на удаленние строк из базы если в указаных столбцах

```
column_name1 => value  == params1[i]
..................................
column_name3 => value  == params3[i]
```

Или как можно решить эту задачу при помощи единого обращения к базе?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, по крайней мере мне, что вы хотите передавать ... Можете попробовать поработать с `ActiveRecord` и его методом [`deleteAll()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#deleteAll()-detail). Я сам не пробовал, просто заинтересовало и глянул в доки, где и нашёл  это ...

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте этот код, нужно использовать DAO

```
  Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
       ->delete(ModelClass::tableName(), ['key' => $value], $params = [])
       ->execute();
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html